# I accidently clicked Image Creation with TestDisk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery

For anyone familiar with the TestDisk (undeleting software),

I accidently selected 'Image Creation' and it created some file which took up the entire disk space of my Linux partition. I do not know where this file (or files) is and how to delete them. Does anyone know where I could delete this file?

Let me know if I should clarify anything. I can't use this Linux partition anymore because it has no space! [bleh]

Comment: The Image Creation should have had you select a destination filesystem . . . you'll want to delete the image.dd that was created there.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll have to go searching for that! (I was trying to undelete some files, but clearly I should have read the manual :P )

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you created an image of your filesystem on your existing filesystem, meaning it attempted to make an exact copy of the whole partition [maybe both the files and the free space] to the same partition.  Since the disk is full now, that means you've written all over the disk, you're unlikely to recover any files on that partition.

Comment: Ah I see, not awesome! I just want access to my OS at this point :P. I'll have a scavenger hunt for this file now.

Comment: Bam! Found it. Put this as an answer so I can give you credit :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Image Creation in TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Image_Creation) is basically used to make a backup/clone of your disk.  From the docs, it sounds like it's basically just a dd, meaning a sector by sector clone.

It sounds like you should specify a destination filesystem when this option is selected, and it'll create an image.dd file there.  To get your freespace back, you'll want to find that image.dd and delete it.

As an aside, if that linux partition was the same partition that you were hoping to undelete files from, you've probably made it impossible to do so, as the image.dd has likely over-written any of the data that would have been left of the files you were hoping to recover.